# Is there a database of save file locations?

Tags: windows

I'd like to not lose progress in the games I've not completed when I'll be refreshing/resetting my Windows partitions. As such I'd love to know about websites where you put in the game name and get out the save file path.

Are there any?

Comment: I'm kinda tempted to say Google. Appropriately enough, the answer is [often found](http://www.google.com/search?q=skyrim%20save%20files) right here.

Comment: @lunboks I was hoping for something... better :)

Comment: *Steam* has a pretty comprehensive list for steam games in their forums...

Comment: @RavenDreamer A link to that would be good enough for an answer

Comment: Most games released in the past decade will store saves in your user folder, mostly in My Documents and sometimes in the Saved Games folder (Win 7 only). Saving your user folder should save most, if not all, saves.

Comment: @kotekzot Yeah, looking in `$HOME$`, `$HOME$/Appdata/Local`, `$HOME$/Appdata/Roaming`, `$HOME$/My Documents/`, `$HOME$/My Documents/Saved Games` got me many but not _all_ the games on my disk. Notable exceptions include Steam Half Life 1's, Cave Story, Deus Ex 1, ...

Comment: @badp old games tend to store saves in their install dir.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the freeware software GameSave Manager. It has a good database of game save locations/formats and supports steam and even GFWL.

http://www.gamesave-manager.com/